# How to data in a table from another table?

Tags: sql, db2

How can i update 1 table value based on another table ID match ? for example below sql, i want update to tb_test `NAME` to tb_test2 `NAME2` where condition code are same `A001`

[image]

expected result after update 
tb_test `NAME` will become `ALI` where condition code are `A001`

What i've tried so far based on online solution. (Failed to apply)
`update tb_test set tb_test.name = tb_test2.name2 from tb_test A inner join tb_Test2 B on A.code = B.code2`

Comment: Do you want to do this just for the specific example or with possibly more rows in tb_test2? And what `UPDATE` statements have you tried so far? You can embed a `SELECT` into an `UPDATE`.

Comment: yes possible more rows in tb_test2 , the code may have more than 1 ...the screenshot provided just a sample. What important is .. tb_test will be update based on tb_test2 data where if tb_test code and tb_test2 code are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should do:

`update tb_test set name=(select tb2.name2 from tb_test2 tb2 where tb2.code2=code)`

You update the name which is selected from the other table and the code/code2 columns need to match.

Comment: It's worked. But if there's more than one row with the given value, will have error log. `The result of a scalar fullselect, 
SELECT INTO statement, or VALUES INTO statement is more than one row.  ` therefor i add on `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` behind the (tb2.code2=code).. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The correct script would be :

> update tb_test
>   inner join tb_test2 
>   on  tb_test.CODE = tb_test2.CODE2
>   set tb_test.name = tb_test2.NAME2 ;

Comment: error : `an unexpected token "join" was found following " ". expected tokens may include "from"`

Answer (score 0):

The INSERT INTO SELECT statement selects data from one table and inserts it into an existing table. Any existing rows in the target table are unaffected. (w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)